# Floating action button to be ontop of drawer after opening

Tags: flutter

I have a floating action button which opens the drawer. I want it to stay in its place when it opens the drawer and just change the icon to close icon with animation. I couldn't find a good solution to do this.
I tried wrapping inside my drawer with scaffold and adding a floating action button there and using hero widgets so make it look like it stays in its place but didn't help at all.
Is there anyway  to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use foldable Sidebar package to achieve this functionalities that's package is available on :
https://pub.dev/packages/foldable_sidebar

And check this piece of code how to use this :

```
  child: Scaffold(
  body: FoldableSidebarBuilder(
            drawerBackgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            drawer: CustomDrawer(closeDrawer: (){
              setState(() {
                drawerStatus = FDBStatus.FDB_CLOSE; // For Closing the Sidebar
              });
            },),
            screenContents: FirstScreen(), // Your Screen Widget
            status: drawerStatus,
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
              child: Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.white,),
              onPressed: () {
                // To Open/Close Sidebar
                setState(() {
                  drawerStatus = drawerStatus == FDBStatus.FDB_OPEN ? FDBStatus.FDB_CLOSE : FDBStatus.FDB_OPEN;
                });
              }),
        ),
       ),
```